# How to get the child class that called the __init__ method

Tags: python, logging

I have the following class:

```
import cfg
import sqlite3
import logging

# logger = logging ......

class Connection:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(cfg.pathToDatabase)
            self.connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            logger.info("Connection to database at " + cfg.pathToDatabase + " successful")
        except Exception, e:
            logger.critical("Error connecting to database")
            logger.exception(e)
```

This class will be instantiated from *multiple* classes. In the following line:

```
logger.info("Connection to database at " + cfg.pathToDatabase + " successful")
```

I would like to *log* the class that *called* the __ init __ method in the *Connection* class. Is this possible ?

for example, based on the following:

```
class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = Connection()
```

I would like to see this logged:

```
"Connection to database at data.sqlite successful from class: Child"
```

Comment: "Is it bad practise to use a class to represent a connection to a database in this way?" What is "this way"? You have not shown any methods or ways to use your class.

Comment: OK I don't think I need the first question in - i've figured that one out. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you think there will be only classes that `Connection` class gets instantiated from. One can instantiate it from anywhere. And in general it is a bad practice for a class to know who called it, and do something based on that information.

Comment: Thanks for the response - if possible can you explain why it is bad practise, or why it would be bad practise to log which class has called it ? many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import traceback, sys

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            raise StopIteration
        except StopIteration:
            tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
            stack = traceback.extract_stack(tb.tb_frame)
            f = stack[-2]
            print "I was called from %s %s (%s:%s)" % (f[2], f[3], f[0], f[1])

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = C()

def foo():
    A()
    return C()

def main():
    C()
    foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
I was called from main C() (test.py:22)
I was called from __init__ self.c = C() (test.py:15)
I was called from foo return C() (test.py:19)
```

Comment: Do you really need a fake exception for this? I'd have thought Python has a way to get access the stack directly.

Comment: @millimoose, check the traceback.py source. It does exactly the same thing: raises an exception if the frame argument is None.

Comment: @millimoose, that's really arguable, since zen of python says that Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @abbot If we're splitting hairs like this, how is "get the previous traceback frame" less explicit than "get the last frame of a traceback of an exception I created just now"? Explicit does not mean "use the most verbose way there is and avoid any available shorthand", it merely means "make your intent clear". (And I'd say doing the same with 4 less lines of code and a level of nesting would make the intent *clearer*.) Just because exceptions have tracebacks attached does not imply they should be present everywhere you look at tracebacks.